# Output length of openssl_encrypt in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

I'm new to PHP and a bit confused right now. I'm reading up on openssl and playing a bit with openssl_encrypt. I built the following example with:

```py
$data = 'test123456789123455';
$key = 'Lk5Uz3slx3BrAghS1aaW5AYgWZRV0tIX5eI0yPchFz4=';
$iv = '0123456789123456';
$cipher = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, $options=0, $iv);
echo $cipher;
```

The Output is 'MujBKrGLuy6lVxV7AOS8JG2+ByWZ62HVsLrWLw7f2l0=%', i am confused, why my output has 45 Bytes. In the documentation of openssl_encrypt i have read, that PKCS #7 padding is applied automatically without certain presettings. The Blocksize of AES is 16 Bytes, so why has my output 45 Bytes and is not a multiple of 16 Bytes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) returns the ciphertext [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded by default. Base64 decoded, the ciphertext is 32 bytes in size, as expected for a 19 bytes plaintext (padded to 32 bytes with PKCS7).

Comment: ahhh, alright. Thank you!

Comment: @Topaco but $options is set on 0, does this not stand for $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA and so openssl_encrypt returns binary raw data?

Comment: Please s. my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66086386/php-function-of-options-0-flag-in-php-openssl-encrypt#comment116840869_66086386).